# Paypal Payment gateway not working using curl request

Tags: php, paypal

I am trying to integrate paypal payment gateway api, but its responding me integer 1.I am not sure what is going wrong. I am sharing my code here. I am using php. I am gettinig token successfully, if i am changing card details its stop responding or take too much response time.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL);
//open connection
$ch = curl_init();
$client = "Client Id Removed";
$secret = "Secret code Removed";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $client.":".$secret);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "grant_type=client_credentials");
$result = curl_exec($ch);
if(empty($result))die("Error: No response.");
else
{
    $json = json_decode($result);
}
curl_close($ch);
$c = curl_init();
$data = '{
  "intent":"sale",
  "payer": {
    "payment_method": "CREDIT_CARD",
    "funding_instruments": [
      {
        "credit_card": {
          "number": "5454545454545454",
          "type": "mastercard",
          "expire_month": 12,
          "expire_year": 2021,
          "cvv2": 111,
          "first_name": "Joe",
          "last_name": "Shopper"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "transactions":[
    {
      "amount":{
        "total":"7.47",
        "currency":"USD"
      },
      "description":"This is the payment transaction description."
    }
  ]
}
';
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v2/payments/payment");
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST ,"POST");
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data); 
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json","Authorization: Bearer ".$json->access_token));
$result = curl_exec($c);
curl_close($c);
if(empty($result))die("Error: No response.");
else
{
    $json = json_decode($result);
    print_r($result);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Payments API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/v1/) cannot be used to process credit cards directly (payment_method: "CREDIT_CARD") -- see the red message. It was only briefly available in a couple countries and was removed a long time ago when PayPal acquired Braintree.

In effect, Braintree replaced the old classic API PayPal Payments Pro. The REST APIs did not.